# mkelem on branch only

Tags: clearcase

I am using ClearCase 7.1.2 and am working on a project. At some point long before I came along there was a branch (lets call it 'pilot') which eventually became the production code while the main tree was left behind. At this point I need to make a branch off of pilot to implement a new feature but am running into a problem.

I have made my branch and all seems to go well when committing changes to existing files but when I do a `mkelem` the new file ends up on main. I want it on pilot. What would the config spec look like for this or what combination of commands can I piece together to make this a reality?

Right now my config spec looks something like this (going from memory):

```
elements * CHECKEDOUT
elements * main/0 -mkbranch pilot
elements * main/pilot
elements * main/LATEST
```

I'll update once I can see what I have going on there.

Comment: I think you've only shown us an approximation to your cspec since normally the references to `main` would be prefixed with `/`.  Please make sure you use a working cspec (or subset of a working cspec) so that we can be more confident in what you've got and we're trying to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find examples on the [config_spec man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm), as well as [Config spec rules for elements in subbranches](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_config_rules_subbranch.htm).

What you need to do is **first put a label on `pilot` branch** (ie, on all the element present in your view on `pilot` branch), in order to make new versions from a fixed point in time.

Then:

```
elements * CHECKEDOUT
elements * .../my_feature_branch/LATEST
elements * LABEL_ON_PILOT -mkbranch my_feature_branch
elements * main/LATEST -mkbranch my_feature_branch
```

Trying to make branch from the "LATEST" versions of another branch is *really* not recommended: you simply don't know from what you are working on on your new branch.

Comment: So the first thing you have to do after creating the branch is merge the changes between LABEL_ON_PILOT and .../pilot/LATEST onto the feature branch.  Isn't that just make-work?  Would you apply the same argument to branching from /main/LATEST?

Comment: Yeah, version control has not been tight to standards in this project hence some issues. Ideally I wouldn't be in this spot to begin with since the pilot line would be merged with main since main is dead fruit. Only reason I am aiming at latest is I am afraid to miss any bug fixes and clobber/leave them behind on release. Not an ideal environment but about 100x better than my last employment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: "first thing"? No, but at least you can easily compare between work from `pilot` and work from `my_feature_branch`. And merge whenever you want.

Comment: Would your label be a release version label, or a new one created for 'start of feature (branch) work'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: a new one for marking the start of the branch. In UCM term, that would be a baseline made, just to be used as a foundation baseline for a sub-stream.

Comment: I've updated my answer to note your concern.  Since branches take 12 hours to apply on our systems (for a 'full label'), it is not a practical proposition for us.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: sure, but I cannot +1 it (I really tried hard to not -1, because I know who you are). And 12 hours for a mklabel? That is why UCM forces you to split your Vob in components. To avoid working with a gazillion files as a all. Again, I am sure you make it work. But I know that, in lesser experienced hands, this (huge vob with no label before branching) is a recipe for disaster. I have seen it. No later than today.

Comment: I've +1'd your answer so it appears first, since no-one else is doing anything about it (probably there are just 3 of us paying any attention at all: you, me and Rig). Since we don't have all the details about the size of system that Rig is dealing with, we can't be sure what will work for him. Our CC guru also reminded me that we had a CM disaster similar to what Rig ran into (development on a branch and /main/LATEST in chaos) about 10 years ago. We did some careful work to reset everything so we could revert to working off /main/LATEST, with a copy-merge from a label on the dev-branch.

Comment: Ok, I have tried this however my new elements are still appearing in the wrong location. Instead of /main/pilot/my_feature_branch it is ending up in /main/my_feature_branch. What is the dealio?

Comment: @Rig: this is by design and normal: a new element is meant to be created directly in the target branch `my_feature_branch`, and has no previous version done in `pilot`: only one in `/main/0`

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd be expecting to see a cspec like this:

```
elements * CHECKEDOUT
elements * .../my_feature_branch/LATEST
elements * .../pilot/LATEST -mkbranch my_feature_branch
elements * /main/LATEST -mkbranch my_feature_branch
```

The `-mkbranch` on the last line answers your question.  Line 2 ensures you use your feature branch when it exists.  The change on line 3 should work better than your line 2 (unless CC 7.1.2 has some new abbreviations which allows your old version to work; I seem to be using 7.0.x).

---

Treat this answer of mine with some caution - see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884041/mkelem-on-branch-only/8884611#8884611) by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) for an alternative way of doing this.  Clearly, there is some issue which VonC sees with this approach.  However, the team I work on has been doing precisely this for many years (since about 1994) without running into the issues which have VonC so up in arms.  In addition, it takes about 12 hours to apply a full label to the set of VOBs which make up our product set (somewhere around a dozen large multi-site VOBs, at a guess).  I checked the time with our CC guru, and he commented that we won't be migrating to UCM any time soon, in part because of this labelling issue.

So, best modern practice with small VOBs may use a label created specifically as a starting point for a feature branch, but not all systems use them.  Empirically, the label is not necessary.  I'm not sure what other 'best practices' (or 'worst practices that compensate for the lack of best practices') we have that prevent us running into problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Oy, I think this is correct but I have group permissions issues. This all seems so complex compared to my time with subversion and git...

Comment: @Rig I wouldn't recommend making a branch from the `LATEST` of another branch. Really dangerous practice.

Comment: @VonC: Why do you regard branching from the LATEST version of another branch as dangerous?  Especially if that is now effectively their main development branch?  How would you write the cspec?

Comment: I can definitely perceive the danger of branching on latest but I am sort of stuck based on practices prior to my involvement on this project :(

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I just spend *hours* trying to debug a team which started a work without a clear starting point. Believe me, your answer is *not* helping.

Comment: @VonC: I've spent years working on a system where that's what we do and I'm not aware of ever having run into problems, either for myself or my colleagues.  I'm not sure whether that makes us lucky or unaware.  We don't apply labels as frequently as I think your modus operandi implies would be necessary.  I'm not saying that its a good thing or a bad thing; it is just the way we've 'always' worked (meaning since 1994).  Blissful ignorance is sometimes blissful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I have no doubt you and tour team made it work, because of your experience. But I am quite frustrating right now because of that kind of answer which, used by a team which doesn't quite know what it is doing, will end up with a *big* problem. I am all the more frustrated that I just got home after 2 hours of debugging that *exact* situation. No label made before the branch, no easy way to go back.